# No encuentra comando "tail" en Symfony

Tags: symfony4

Siguiendo el tutorial de la documentación de Symfony [Symfony. Servicios](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony/services#play) veo que no puedo ejecutar el siguiente comando `tail -f var/log/dev.log`. Lo estoy probando también con `php tail -f var/log/dev.log` debido a que era la forma que estaba ejecutando los comandos hasta ahora pero me sale un error diciendo que no reconoce el comando "tail". Cuando ejecuto el comando, el servidor esta parado puesto que no se puede ejecutar ningún comando mientras este corriendo el servidor(o por lo menos yo no sé la manera de correr servidor y ejecutar comandos al mismo tiempo). 
¿Alquién sabe por que no puedo ejecutar dicho comando tail?

Comment: tail es un comando de linux no de symfony, si estas trabajando en windows no va a funcionar

Comment: Gracias, eso explica que no encuentre tal comando. ¿Sabrías si hay algo equivalente para la terminal de windows?

Answer (score 0):

Tail es un comando que se utiliza en linux y no es del framework Symfony

Tail en linux: te dejo un tutorial de como activarlo para poder utilizarlo:
[Tail en linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905012/what-package-is-tail-included-with)

Tail en windows
Sigue este tutorial para instalarlo en windows:
[Tail en Windows](https://www.windows-commandline.com/tail-command-for-windows/)